# How to Get a Random Map in Google Play Game Service Real-time Multiplayer Game

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I’m trying to get my game to work so that when players play auto-matched game the players will play on a randomly selected map. I tried room.getCreationTimestamp() to use the last digit’s remainder as an index of a map, but it seems that the creation time stamp isn’t the same for different players. I also tried the room id to get a byte from there but the id isn’t either same for every player.

So is there a variable or a field in the room that would be different in different games but same for each player in the same game or which would be the alternative way to get a randomly selected map that would be same for each player.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simply generate a random number on one side and push it to the other?

Comment: You mean like one player creates random number and sends it as a message to all the other players?

Comment: Yeah. The device that created the game (server) can also generate a random number. Any other player's devices (clients) can then request this number or the server can push them to the clients.

Comment: There isn’t a server device in Google Game Services auto-match game. But maybe I could use some method to decide which generates a random number.

Comment: Is this a turn based game or a realtime game?

Comment: Oh it is realtime. I should have mention that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the game generate a random number by some other means and then push this number to all other players.

If all devices are considered equal (no server/client arrangement) then you need to decide which device generates the random number. For a turn based game this is easy. Yours is realtime so possibly more awkward.

This is what I would do...

For realtime games the flow should be as follows for each player's device;

- Read the IDs of all players, for this you can use `getParticipantIds()` on a `Room` object of some kind
- Get the ID for this device/player this can be done for a given room using `getParticipantId ()` on a `Participant` object (I presume you have one)
- Decide which ID should be the one to make the random number. The simplest way to do this is to select the lowest participant ID
- If the selected ID is the ID of the current device then generate a random number and send it as a message to all other participants
- If the selected ID is not the ID of the current device then wait for a message with the random number.

That should do it. All players can now agree on a random number.